# Proof multivariable function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Having trouble understanding this proof from Pugh's Real Mathematical Analysis 2nd Edition (p. 288).

Theorem. A function $f:U → \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at $p ∈ U$ if and only if
each of its components $f_i$ is differentiable at $p$. Furthermore, the derivative of its $i^{th}$
component is the $i^{th}$ component of the derivative.

Proof. Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $p$ and express the $i^{th}$ component of $f$ as
$f_i$ = $\pi_if$ where $\pi_i : \mathbb{R}^m → \mathbb{R}$ is the projection that sends a vector $w = (w_1, . . . , w_m)$ to $w_i$. Since $\pi_i$ is linear it is differentiable. By the Chain Rule, $f_i$ is differentiable at $p$ and $(Df_i)_p = (D\pi_i) \circ (Df)_p = \pi_i \circ (Df)_p$.

(1) Is $\pi_if$ a composition of two functions (the lack of $\circ$ is confusing me)? If not, what is it?

(2) On the last equality, how does $(D\pi_i)$ become $\pi_i$? I understand this to mean that the derivative of a function, $\pi_i$, is equal to itself? I thought this was only possible for the exponential function?

Comment: (1) Yes, it is the composition (2) The derivative of a linear map is itself. $\pi_i$ is a linear map.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that.